# Copying a lookup field of the current item in workflow gives an error

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I'm generating a reference number in a custom list in sharepoint designer. The process then waits for that to be set and copies the reference number across to a new entry in a tasks list.

The

The reference number in the custom list is of type 'single line of text' and is the title column in the list. In the tasks list the field is a lookup field but fails to take the reference across and gives:

**Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type.**

Has anyone had any experience with this issue on workflow

Comment: Are you copy/pasting the lookup field to another area?

Answer (score 2):

I am very new to SharePoint so I am not conversant with its jargon. Being someone that comes from a relational database background, am going to explain this best way I can and hope it helps out.

So in my case, the conflict is as a result of a data type miss match. The lookup column in the library expects a value of data type **integer** while I was of input a **string** value hence the '*Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type.*' error.

I discovered that the lookup column in my library did not use my 'primary key' to make reference to the other list where I needed to get my values from.

[image: DocID is what I am using as a primary key in my library]

Instead what is used as a reference column is a system generated column named ID and is of type **integer**. Simply changing the *field from source* to ID fixed my problem.

[image: Change field from source to ID]

Answer (score -1):

works when the field is set to ID instead

Comment: could you elaborate on this?